# Prepration of standards for analysis of chromium using AAS

Tags: analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis, geochemistry

I have conducted experiments to study specific adsorption of chromium in various soils and I made my all solutions of cr with using 0.01M NaNO3 as background electrolyte. (I made solutions of 5 different ppm concentrations)
So now for calibration of the AAS instrument should I prepare standards using only distilled water or my background solution( electrolyte).

Comment: How are you preparing your Cr standard and instrument do you have? What is the concentration range? Write more details. Cr analysis on AAS requires more special conditions.

Comment: IMHO, the rate and efficiency of metal atomization may strongly depend on the dissolved matrix..... I would try to make as many variables constant as possible.

Comment: What do you mean when stating that you "made solutions of 5 different ppm concentrations" ? Five different concentrations of what ? Of chromium or of NaNO3 ? And are the ppm concentrations expressed in weight per liter or in mole per liter ? Weight or mole of what ?

Comment: @Maurice I made 5 different solutions of cr (e.g 1 2 4 8 ppm.chromium and made up the volume with 0.01M sodium nitrate.)

Comment: @Poutnik okay thanks I am thinking about making the standards also with sodium nitrate. I mean Im thinking about diluting my stock solution using the NaNO3 solution

Comment: What is the reason for the sodium nitrate? Does it have an effect on the Cr atom concentration in the flame? If YES it must also be in the standards. If NO you best rethink your method. Remember AA analysis requires that the element must be converted quantitatively into atoms under the flame conditions for best results.

Comment: @jimchmst okay I think Calibration solutions and my samples should have similar chemical composition so I thought I should make standards also with sodium nitrate. I am not sure of effect of chromium concentration I don't think it will impact the concentration in any way.